# How to add quality selector to react-video.js

Tags: reactjs, video.js

I Want to add a quality selector to videojs in react

I have implemented the following code but it does not help
player.hlsQualitySelector({
displayCurrentQuality: true,
});

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example illustrating the issue you are having? I am having trouble understanding from the description...

Comment: I have solve that problem but my new problem is that I don't know how to send master.m3u8 file from backend to frontend, Can you help me with that?